# Do I need to create an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2015 to work with AngularJS?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio

> Do I need to create an ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2015 to work with AngularJS?

I want to learn and test AngularJS in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, but I don't want to start an ASP.NET project, since I do not want to use this technology.

How can I create a "plain" project like I would do in Webstorm?

Comment: After picking ASP.Net Web Application, pick the Blank Template.  This creates a simple website that only includes ASP.Net in order to provide IISExpress as a server for testing.  It doesn't include any ASP.Net content.

Answer (score 1):

Just Create a blank solution and start implementing your code in VS2015.

Comment: Why do most online tutorials start the ASP.NET version?

Comment: they want to merge Asp.net back-end logic like database manipulation to front-end angular.